# Dependency injection with storyboards

Tags: swift, initialization, storyboard, protocols

I am trying to pass dependency into a view controller instantiated from storyboard using the following code

```
init?(coder: NSCoder, alertPresenter: AlertPresenterProtocol = , viewModel: EmployeesViewModel) {
        self.alertPresenter = alertPresenter
        self.employeeViewModel = viewModel
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
```

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

But I get the fatalError message. How can I pass dependency to a view controller through the initializer when it is instantiated from storyboard

Comment: “But I get the fatalError message.” Because that is what you said to do.

Comment: Also please show real code.

Comment: the question is how can I pass dependency to a view controller through the initializer when it is instantiated from storyboard

Comment: This is what `prepareForSegue` is for.

Comment: I am not using this to pass variables between view controller. I am trying to make the view controller testable

Comment: Then ask about that. We can only answer the question that is actually asked. And the question actually asked is easy to answer. Only init(coder) is called, and it says crash so you crash. Done.

Comment: We call this an XY problem. You wrongly assume X is how to do Y and then you complain that X doesn’t work, instead of asking about Y.

Comment: Besides, in a unit test there isn’t going to be any storyboard involved.

Comment: The question is very simple , how can I pass dependency through initializer for a view controller instantiated form storyboard

Comment: Well from where are you going to inject your dependencies then when the VC is instantiated from the storyboard? _You_ are not calling init so I am curious.

Comment: I agree with Joakim Danielson. You say "The question is very simple , how can I pass dependency through initializer for a view controller instantiated form storyboard". But you are not _calling_ the initializer for a view controller instantiated from the storyboard. The runtime is calling it, and _it_ is not going to pass a dependency. It's going to call `init(coder:)` and you are going to crash. Indeed, your code suggests that you are _never_ expecting this view controller to come from a storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't.

You instantiate a view controller from the storyboard using the `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` method of `UIStoryboard`. According to the docs:

> Each time you call this method, it creates a new instance of the view controller using the init(coder:) method.

The method creates the view controller for you, and it does not provide any way for you to inject dependencies.

When the view controller is created by a *segue*, the `prepareForSegue` method provides you with a `UIStoryboardSegue` object that has a reference to the already-initialized `destination` view controller. No way to inject dependencies via the initializer here, either.

Some purists will throw this fact in your face as a reason why you shouldn't use storyboards.

Personally, I've never found that to be a compelling argument. I simply assign the dependencies as properties of the view controller after it's been instantiated. This works just fine for unit testing, too. This does mean that your dependencies will have to be declared as optionals, and this can make your code a little less elegant. Again, I don't see this as a compelling reason to give up the many conveniences of storyboards.

Comment: Actually, that is _not_ the reason why you shouldn't use storyboards. The reason is partly that they don't play well with Git collaboration and partly that you can't combine storyboard segues with router / coordinator / presenter architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Your storyboard must use a method marked with @IBSegueAction which will accept with minimum coder argument and returns object which correspond to destination. Inside that method you should init your destination view controller with custom init method.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. :) Segue actions have not been accepted by the general programming populace. People seem not to have noticed that they exist. But they are great! They allow you to combine your own code with storyboard instantiation of the segue destination.

Comment: @matt maybe you can help me to see if this feature have some limitations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285494/storyboard-dependency-injection-for-scene-with-custom-objects

Answer (score -2):

If the dependency can be derived from within the initializer `init?(coder:)`, you do so, and set it there.

If it's not, you can't set it there.

In any case, since you said unit-tests were involved, you'll want to make the dependency an externally settable attribute, and set it from the unit-test.