# Storyboard dependency injection for scene with custom objects

Tags: ios, uikit, storyboard

I have a custom init? method on destination scene called ListCountriesViewController which is called inside a method "createListCountriesViewController" located in ViewController and set on a storyboard segue instantiation property at "Connection Inspector" which connects ViewController and ListCountriesViewController scenes. ListCountriesViewController contains a custom object which is created via storyboard "Object". When segue executes the method "createListCountriesViewController" is executed twice, and the second execution terminates with NSExeption:

> Thread 1: "Custom instantiated
> <pocStoryboardDependencyInjection.ListCountriesViewController:
> 0x148005e40> must be kind of class
> pocStoryboardDependencyInjection.CustomObject"

after deleting the custom object from storyboard scene the problem is solved.

Is Storyboard Dependency Injection, which was included in UIKit/iOS 13, compatible with objects which are set on scene like: Objects (custom class), Additional views (custom class), Gestures (custom class) If yes, how can I solve my problem?

[image]

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBSegueAction
    func createListCountriesViewController(_ coder: NSCoder, sender: Any?, segueIdentifier: String?) -> ListCountriesViewController? {
        let controller = ListCountriesViewController(coder, userForm: ["field1"])
        return controller
    }

}

class ListCountriesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var customObject: CustomObject!

    init?(_ coder: NSCoder, userForm: UserForm) {
        self.userForm = userForm
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

}

class CustomObject: NSObject {
    
}
```

Comment: Very well asked. You could have simplified the example considerable (we don't need a table view controller here, nor do we need to know what a "real" custom object would look like), but you've demonstrated the issue perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Storyboard Dependency Injection, which was included in UIKit/iOS 13, compatible with objects which are set on scene like: Objects, Additional views, Gestures ?

Evidently not. As your example demonstrates (perfectly), the mere presence of the additional top-level object in the scene causes the segue action to misbehave. No reference / outlet to the storyboard CustomObject is needed to elicit the crash.

I regard this as a bug; you should file a report with Apple.

Comment: I read your answer as you would state: If your UIStoryboard scene has a objects, views and gesture objects on root level then instantiation of the scene will be impossible with the view controller custom init method. I am right ?

Comment: Revised my answer but the answer is the same. I think you have beautifully demonstrated a bug and you should file a report with Apple.

Comment: I have also edited my question in place where I was stating about additional root level objects. After additional tests I can state that scene additional root level objects leads to crash when set to use custom subclass.

Comment: Oh! So a mere NSObject would not cause the issue?

Comment: yes, a mare NSObject would not cause the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your question more than once. :) Very nice work but I don't see how we can say more at this point.

Comment: I am still under iOS14. I will check this issue under UIKit15 soon.

Comment: It's the same on iOS 15, I assure you.